# SQLite delete the "worst" duplicates

Tags: sqlite, duplicates

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `laptimes` (
`driver`    varchar NOT NULL,
`car`   varchar NOT NULL,
`laptimeMs` int NOT NULL,
);
```

filled with data like in this example:

```
| driver| car   | laptimeMs|
| ----- | ----- | ---------|
| John  | Toyota| 99999    |
| john  | Toyota| 100000   |
| Bob   | Ford  | 123456   |
```

As you can see I messed up big time by not taking care of the letter cases in the `driver` column so now I have driver+car combination duplicates like in the example. I want to delete those duplicates which have worse (bigger) `laptimeMs` values. The closest I could get to what I want is using this query:

```
delete from laptimes
where rowid not in
         (
         select min(rowid)
         from laptimes
         group by driver COLLATE NOCASE, car
         )
```

But of course this will simply delete the first duplicate entries it finds, it doesn't care about the `laptimeMs` value. I thought replacing the `select min(rowid)` part with `select max(laptimeMs)` would do the trick but that doesn't work, it just wipes all data. Then I tried to add `order by laptimeMs desc` like this

```
delete from laptimes
where rowid not in
         (
         select min(rowid)
         from laptimes
         group by driver COLLATE NOCASE, car
         order by laptimeMs desc
         )
```

That didn't seem to make any difference.

Can someone help me with this please? Just to be clear - the middle row with value `100000` is the one I want to get rid of in the example.

Edit: The answer by @Tim Biegeleisen was close to what I needed. Exact query that worked for me:

```
DELETE
FROM laptimes
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM laptimes t
    WHERE t.driver = laptimes.driver COLLATE NOCASE AND
          t.car = laptimes.car AND
          t.laptimeMs < laptimes.laptimeMs
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use exists logic here:

```sql
DELETE
FROM laptimes
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM laptimes t
    WHERE t.driver = laptimes.driver AND
          t.laptimeMs < laptimes.laptimeMs
);
```

Comment: `near "t1": syntax error:` Is this even SQLite? :)

Comment: @Lakyn Sorry, for whatever reason I thought you were using MySQL.  Please try the updated answer.

Comment: Awesome, this was very close to what I needed. I just added `COLLATE NOCASE` to the driver string comparison so it ignores case and added car string comparison so it compares driver+car combinations. I updated my post with the exact query. Thank you, Tim!